# Flutter - Search Using API Url

Tags: flutter, dart, autocomplete

I have google books API Url "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=", in that URL have a parameter q=, i want when user search, all data fetch showing with autocomplete, sorry if I'm bad to explain this question, thank you